# How to override a render to create a custom "render :my_format => argument" in rails 2.3(.5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, render, applicationcontroller

I would like to create a custom render as specified in title.

For instance, I have my controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @objs }
    end
  end
end
```

, but I would like something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @objs }
      format.my_format  { render :my_format => @objs }
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible? What are the steps I need to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I want something like in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads). So I replaced the @objs with a method but it didn't work either (the method wasn't called).

Obs: I register the mime type at config/initializers/mime_types.rb.

Answer (score 3):

From [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods.html#M001808):

> "If you need to use a MIME type which
>   isn’t supported by default, you can
>   register your own handlers in
>   environment.rb as follows."

```
  Mime::Type.register "image/jpg", :jpg
```

Comment: Suppose we already have a mime type registered.

Taking your answer as an example, we could want to serve a dynamically generated jpg image with this format option in MyController: "format.jpg { render :jpg => @shapes }". Is it possible? How?